# Creating same design and pattern, with different domain name for the organization

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, alter

I got the project, for building the exactly same with a different domain name, on the WordPress, as we had to complete the project quickly, I have suggested them I can use the source code of the parent HTML or through cloning, which they agree upon as they told me create new site will require new admin WordPress, the owners authorize me to built new website, taking services from WordPress and built the site through web browser.

I have built the website with new domain and site registration with adding US name for the organization which is different from parent organization, through copying the HTML code of the parent site with some alteration in the headings, for the US, and when the site is explored further definitely it will show in the address bar of the original site name with link. That needed to be change according to the customer, the address bar and task bar address, of the browser, should not show parent site with link, and just the new site name.or with link because they want to keep them separate. Please can you tell me how to do that and after making the site live I have created staging site, when I am changing address of the company, through theme nothing is changing.

I created the Astra theme, with Eliminator Pro I formatted the page and then I pasted the html source code. Problem 1 Company original Logo is not is also changing, as USA needed to be added in
Created the satagging mode and made the site live.  I tried to change in the HTML in appearances -- theme file editor with Alias (but it didn't change the address) and will take great time to do what is the best way to do alias and I want to change some information on the page  but  nothing is changing and how to read source code and determine what other support and  what type of plug-ins I need to add.

Comment: Nothing to do with JS. You basically need to set the logo from WP admin, same as all the other page / article modifications. All those changes are stored in the related website's WP's database. If you decide to edit the template for both websites you edit just the template files and upload to **both**. Everything else that makes those pages slightly different should be customizable from the WP admin.

Comment: When in need of migrating / cloning a wordpress installation, I for one use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/ to replace the original domain name with the new one in DB. That way, whatever was pointing to the old domain gets changed to point to the new domain.

Answer (score 1):

As comment above, this isn’t related with JS.
Let me try to answer few checklist that can help you. Since you are clone exiting website (abc.com) to new domain website (xyz.com) keep same standard but new link path.

- Depending if you keeping same hosting service (Godaddy, AWS, etc) for new web hosting (xyz.com) as existing web (abc.com). If yes, then please check with hosting service provider to get best practice how you can clone and replicate it for new wordpress (xyz.com). This is good practice because all hosting service provider or cloud provide does provide similar feature to do it in few clicks rather than whole manual process technical process. This will save time. Please note that few web host can do this for you under cost. So better to log support case with web hosting.
- Let’s asume you have VPS or you planning to deploy production environment, If this wordpress instance is under Virtual umbrella like VM, Hyper-v, Docker, Kubernette. Then I would suggest to replicate from infrastructure layer. Because this will save time configuring it.
- Let’s assume you creating new wordpress environment. And you want to migrate. Please keep the wordpress version does correspond with new instance. I assume existing wordpress (abc.com) is running on latest version. So makes sure same version is install on new instance (xyz.com)
- I don’t advise to copy/paste file via ftp or manually exporting DB. Because majority of time, it could break stuff or any random error during import makes time consuming troubleshooting. So I advice to use ‘ All-in-One WordPress Migration’ by ‘ServMask’ plugin to create export and import to new wordpress. (I have tested and used paid version in my projects but free version can do the trick and easy to do copy wordpress files and db).
- Please Note you need to increase upload size of new wordpress instance since you will import the files. Default values are 2M so you can google various articles how increase upload value.
- Once you have clone the wordpress, makes sure to change site_url and wordpress url as per these step => https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/blogs/wordpress-url-change/#:~:text=The%20WordPress%20address%20(site%20URL,website%20can%20be%20reached%20externally.
- As you using Elementor, you can use this built-in feature to replace (abc.com) links to (xyz.com) => https://elementor.com/help/i-changed-the-url-of-my-website-and-elementor-does-not-work-anymore/
- Some deep links, doesn’t get change via elementor ‘Replace URL’ option. So you still need to test and open all pages and posts in developer mode and check source files and do quick search with old domain, if it find some non-replace link and then you can trace back and codes, JS script to replace the (abc.com) to (xyc.com).
- Make sure to modify any contact forms, newsletters or SMTP configured within elementor forms.
- Keep wordpress default wordpress theme if you will be using elementor as front-end. Using non-default wordpress theme with elementor could be bugy when elementor plugins are pushed by updates. So not advicable.
- Inserting ‘complete structured HTML source code’ as short code (asuming your old instance is generic html web) via elementor isn’t recommend. This will break images specifically. I encourage to redesign it via elementor canvas as templates and later links it as short code. This might be time saving.
- I haven’t tested personally but worth to try html to elementor convertor. => [https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/how-convert-html-to-elementor/#:~:text=How%20to%20Add%20HTML%20to,Google%20into%20the%20Elementor%20editor](https://www.websitebuilderinsider.com/how-convert-html-to-elementor/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Add%20HTML%20to,Google%20into%20the%20Elementor%20editor).
- If you have any SEO plugin, don’t forget to modify the details and check .xml site map to see if all pages are pointing towards new domain. Sometimes just resave page updates the domains names.
- Last but not least, before moving to production, please test all installed/migrated plugins. Because in some situation html code based wordpress plugins doesn’t like elementor plugin and could cause bug. So to keep new instance with essential plugins.

I hope this posts answer your query.